# Draw upside down asterisk triangle

Tags: java, nested-loops

OUTPUT

```
          *****
           ***
            *
```

Code (my attempt)

```
    for (int lines = 3; lines >= 1; lines--)
    {
        if (lines == 3) 
            System.out.printf("%1s", " ");
        else if (lines == 2)
            System.out.printf("%2s", " ");
        else if (lines == 1)
            System.out.printf("%3s", " ");

        for (int stars = 1; stars <=  2* lines - 1; stars++);
        {
            System.out.print('*');
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

and I get this:

```
     *
       *
         *
```

I cannot find the problem, the code should run and work

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so we can help you.

Comment: So you are not even going to try to do your own homework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     for (int lines = 3; lines >= 1; lines--)
     {
         if (lines == 3) 
            System.out.printf("%1s", " ");
         else if (lines == 2)
            System.out.printf("%2s", " ");
         else if (lines == 1)
            System.out.printf("%3s", " ");

         for (int stars = 1; stars <=  2* lines - 1; stars++)
            System.out.print('*');

         System.out.println();
      }
```

I HAD A ";" AFTER MY SECOND FOR LOOP IN THE ORIGINAL WHICH CAUSED IT TO ONLY RUN ONCE AND NOT BE A LOOP!

Comment: Please turn off caps lock

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, perhaps:

```
for(int lines = 3; lines >= 1; lines--)
{
 if (lines == 1)    
    System.out.printf("%3s", " ");`
else if (lines == 2)
    System.out.printf("%2s", " ");
else if (lines == 3)
    System.out.printf("%1s", " ");

for(int stars = 1; stars <= 2 * lines - 1; stars++)
    System.out.print ('*');

System.out.println();
}
```

You were on the right path, but basically, you only need to reverse the first "for" loop (make it count down instead of up)[this part was done correctly], adjust the script to do 3 lines instead of 4 [also done correctly], and leave the second "for" loop as it was originally, because it already takes into account how many lines there are//which line you are on from previous code. I hope this made sense and solved your problem. :P

Comment: I still get just 3 " * " in a downward diagonal

Comment: :o It works for me, are you sure you copied it correctly? :P

Comment: yep, I am not sure what the issue is :/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this; although the code is not neat, it works, and it's based on your original code:

```
for(int stars =5,lines = 1,j; lines <= 4; lines++)
             {
                 if (lines == 1)    
                    System.out.printf("%1s", " ");
                else if (lines == 2)
                    System.out.printf("%2s", " ");
                else if (lines == 3)
                    System.out.printf("%3s", " ");
                else if (lines == 4)
                    System.out.printf("%4s", " ");
                j=stars;
                for(  ; j > 0; j--)
                    System.out.print ('*');
                stars-=2;
                System.out.println();
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your home work stuff and you can learn more about these star pattern in this link.[Star Pattern Example](http://www.sitesbay.com/java-program/java-triangle-of-star)

Anyway, for your **Star** program case, I think you are looking for solution like below.

```
int i, j, k;
for (i = 4; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (j = 5; j > i; j--) {
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (k = 1; k < (i * 2); k++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Hope it help.